# can I set several state params with one mutation in Vuex?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a store with several state parameters and some (not all!) should be reset to their initial values.

I wonder if I can have one mutation to change several keys in vuex or is it a bad practice?

So it would look like that:

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        a: 0,
        b: 2,
        c: 1,
        
        z: 0
},
     mutations: {
        RESETALL: (state) => {
            state.a = 0;
            state.b = 2;
            ...
            state.z = 0;
        },
```

Comment: Generally mutations are supposed to be fine-grained, but if single mutations like `a = 0` don't make sense in separate, RESETALL looks ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is **Yes**. You can, *and should*, change multiple state parameters in a single mutation.

- this saves you time
- this saves you from typing many lines of code
- this models your application in a nice way

What do I mean by that last point? Instead of an action that does this:

```js
async loadData() {
  commit("setLoading", true);
  commit("setData", []);
  commit("setError", "");
  const newData = await axios.get("/data");
  commit("setData", newData);
  commit("setLoading", false);
}
```

You could have an action that expresses what it's doing and why:

```js
async loadData() {
  commit("loadingData");
  const newData = await axios.get("/data");
  commit("applyNewlyLoadedData", newData);
}
```

The mutations then look like:

```js
loadingData = (state) => {
  state.loading = true;
  state.data = [];
  state.error = "";
},
applyNewlyLoadedData = (state, payload) => {
  state.data = payload;
  state.loading = false;
},
```

This leads to simpler actions (which I typically see grow into complex beasts), and slightly more complex mutations (which typically do very little and make the mutation layer much more useless than it need be).

Answer (score 1):

You could make an init, set, clear etc, for example:

```
import Vue from 'vue'

/**
 * State for thing
 *
 * Usage: this.$store.state.thing.*
 */
const defaultState = {
  someDefaultProp: true,
  foo: null,
  bar: null
}
export const state = () => ({
   ...defaultState
})

/**
 * Mutations / Setters
 *
 * Usage: this.$store.commit('thing/<method name>', payload)
 */
export const mutations = {
  /**
   * Initialize/hydrate state
   *
   * Usage: this.$store.commit('thing/init', {id: 123})
   *
   * @param {Object} state
   * @param {Object} data
   */
  init (state, data) {
    // hydrate passed vars
    for (const i in data) {
      Vue.set(state, i, data[i])
    }
  },

  /**
   * Set single state item
   *
   * Usage: this.$store.commit('thing/set', {key: 'id', value: 123})
   *
   * @param {*} state
   * @param {*} param1
   */
  set (state, {
    key,
    value
  }) {
    Vue.set(state, key, value)
  },

  /**
   * Clear state, set to null
   * @param {*} state
   */
  clear (state) {
    // set all to null
    for (const i of Object.keys(state)) {
      state[i] = typeof defaultState[i] === 'undefined' ? null : defaultState[i]
    }
  }
}
```

Then use like:

- init: `this.$store.commit('thing/init', {foo: 123, bar:'baz'})`
- set: `this.$store.commit('thing/set', {key: 'bar', value: 'boo'})`
- clear `this.$store.commit('thing/clear')`

Answer (score -1):

Mutation have the access to the whole state object, you can mutate(init, set, clear) the whole state if you want..